# Subclassing QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt

I am trying to subclass QTreeWidgetItem so I can fill-in class with data I need.
Went through all the code and couldn't find one complete example on how to do it right. 
In my implementation something is wrong because application won't start up, but if I do it with QTreeWidgetItem then it works without any problems.

So I have created subclass as H file:

```
#ifndef XITEM_H
#define XITEM_H

#include <QTreeWidget>

class XItem :  public QObject,public QTreeWidgetItem
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    XItem ();
    void setText(int column, const QString &atext);
    void addChild(QTreeWidgetItem *child);
};

#endif
```

And C file:

```
#include "X.h"

XItem ::XItem (): QTreeWidgetItem(UserType)
{

}

void XItem::setText(int column, const QString &atext){
    setText(column,atext);
}

void XItem::addChild(QTreeWidgetItem *child){
    addChild(child);
}
```

And code that runs it all:

```
QTreeWidget * tree = ui->treeWidget;

QTreeWidgetItem * topLevel = new QTreeWidgetItem();

topLevel->setText(0, "This is top level");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    //QTreeWidgetItem * item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    XItem *item = new XItem();
    item->setText(0,"item " + QString::number(i+1));
    topLevel->addChild(item);
}

tree->addTopLevelItem(topLevel);
```

If I run it like this application hangs and if I comment:

```
XItem *item = new XItem();
```

and un-comment:

```
QTreeWidgetItem * item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
```

it works.

Could anyone help out on this please.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway... after all years still simple mistake as this one can come along long hours coding.

ERROR:

```
void XItem::setText(int column, const QString &atext){
    setText(column,atext);
}

void XItem::addChild(QTreeWidgetItem *child){
    addChild(child);
}
```

Should be:

```
void XItem::setText(int column, const QString &atext){
    QTreeWidgetItem::setText(column,atext);
}

void XItem::addChild(QTreeWidgetItem *child){
    QTreeWidgetItem::addChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is not necessary for these methods to be declared and implemented in the child class. Inheritance makes children have the same methods of parents, that is one of their advantages, try eliminating both methods.

Comment: Tnx for answering, you are 100% correct but I have left it to point out the problem.